# Catch 504 (Gateway Timeout) Error in React, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, server

I have a working API to get items from the server as below. I am using React to use this data. Now, I want to catch all server errors that begins with 5__ and display a message like "No connection with internet" or something like that.

```
 export const GetItems = (operand, searchValue) => {
      const trimmedValue = searchValue.trim();
      let combinedResults;
      // make 2 API calls to search on both item_name and code;
      // then combine them;
      // there is no API method to do this, that I could find
      return getItemsByName(operand, trimmedValue)
      .then(result => (
        (combinedResults = [].concat(result))
      ))
      .then(() => getItemsByCode(operand, trimmedValue))
      .then(result => (
        (combinedResults = combinedResults.concat(result))
      ));
    };
```

Currently, I need to look at the console to check if there is a problem with connection.

[image: 504 Gateway Timeout Error]

---

**Updated as @Dane requested**

```
const getItemsByCode = (operand, searchValue) => (
  FetchToJson(BuildCodeSearchUrl(operand, searchValue))
);
```

It's just calling a method to build the URL. You can consider that everything is working good, getting the response if there is a connection.

Comment: Can you please add the code for `getItemsByCode` as well ?

Comment: wat http library are you using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `catch()`:

```
return getItemsByName(operand, trimmedValue)
      .then(result => (
        (combinedResults = [].concat(result))
      ))
      .then(() => getItemsByCode(operand, trimmedValue))
      .then(result => (
        (combinedResults = combinedResults.concat(result))
      ))
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) { // if there is response, it means its not a 50x, but 4xx

        } else {   // gets activated on 50x errors, since no response from server
          // do whatever you want here :)
        }            
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to get error code instead of error message? As I mentioned, I need to catch all errors with status code begins  with 5 (ie; 500,503)

Comment: The error object contains all information you want. I'll update my answer now

Comment: I'm getting this error now
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined at eval`

Comment: Ok sorry, its because in case of 50x errors, you get no responses at all from the server. I've updated my answer

Comment: Hi @Dane, I changed but still having the same error.

Comment: Same error ? Impossible! there is no `status` anywhere in the code above !

Comment: Did you try console logging the `error` as `JSON.stringify(error)`. Then you can actually see all keys inside the `error` object. I can't recall where exactly the status code is, so try console logging... try `error.status` as well See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ru6o090e/

Comment: @SureshPokharel so I hope `error.status` was the thing, ryt ?

Comment: Can we get API details like URL when we catch 504 error?

Comment: Is it possible to catch 504 error using React ErrorBoundary?